# Need to get an array of the names of all applicationScope variables

Tags: javascript, xpages

In an application I am working on I need to get a list of the names of all applicationScope variable then I need to cycle through them and filter out the ones starting with a know string say $xyx. I thought that the applicationScope.keySet().
I'm using this code for starter:
var col = applicationScope.keySet();
var itr:java.util.Iterator = col.iterator();
if (itr.hasNext()){
    var str:String = itr.next();
    dBar.info(str,"Value = ");
}

if I put the variable col in a viewScope it shows a list of all the keys. but when I run the script the values displayed in the dBar info are not the keys but some other information that I'm not sure where it comes from. 
I should just be able to iterat through the list of keys, am I missing something?
This code is in the before page loads event

Answer (score 2):

After some poking around and experimenting I got this to work:

```
var col = applicationScope.keySet();
var itr:java.util.Iterator = col.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    var str:Map.Entry = itr.next();
    if (str.substring(0,9) == "$wfsLock_"){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

so I'm now a happy camper.

Comment: All of the scopes contain entries that are automatically populated by the platform in addition to any custom entries you explicitly add. If the approach you listed meets your needs, be sure to mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: Bill, you are actually at the crossroad to more Java. Have a look at managed beans which give you more control what is stored where and how it gets accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code works in SSJS, it is not correct (and that's why I don't like SSJS...).

The `applicationScope` is an implementation of the [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface and the `keySet()` method returns a `Set` containing the keys in that Map. Every entry is (probably) a `String` (other data types like integers are actually also valid). The line

```
var str:Map.Entry = itr.next();
```

doesn't cast it to a `Map.Entry`: it doesn't really do anything: `str` remains a string.

The Map interface also has an `entrySet()` method that returns the entries (`Map.Entry`). You can use that to retrieve the key as well as the value:

```
var it = applicationScope.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {

    var entry = it.next();
    print( entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() );

}
```

(in this code the `print()` line will use the `toString()` method of the key as well as the value to send information to the console)

I see from your code that you've installed my [XPages Debug Toolbar](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar). You can also use that to quickly check what's in the scopes and what the actual datatype is.

Comment: Thanks Mark, datatypes of the Key and Values in this case are well known and predictable. In fact the Value is an Array. But it try your code.